# What is the best way of moving a 150GB MySQL Server to a new Server in the same datacenter?

Tags: mysql

I currently run a game server with a few hundred players online at all times and I also have a MySQL Server on the same machine, we store multiple logs & game data in the database however the database has reached around 150GB in size and there's only around 40GB left on the disk space so I need to move it eventually. (Around 200 tables, largest one is 35GB)

I've already purchased a new Server for the database with 500GB+ storage. And it's hosted in the same datacenter (ovh).

I've been searching around a bit for the best way to achieve this and here are my results.

1. Set-up a Master/Slave relationship between the servers and eventually make the slave the new master and remove the old mysql server from the game server. (I'd have to zip up the sql via mysqldump to get the slave to the masters position which might not be possible due to my low disk space?).
2. Shut down the Main MySQL Server then move all of the MySQL table files to the new server and launching that one?

The new MySQL Server is running MySQL 8.0.15 and the old one 5.7.14.

Hope you can give me some insight or information!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to move the server files.
Import or master/slaves would be really slow because of mysql insert mecanism.

You may have to launch 'mysql_upgrade' command to update your database as your new server as a more recent version of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried using filezilla FTP via the machines and I am getting 55MBs transfer speeds, does that sound decent?

Comment: 55MB/s => 440Mb/s
If you are in a local network, you may have better results using ftp command directly from your server I think, but it's ok.